# dxl script to paste the clipboard contents in selected objects

Tags: ibm-doors

I want to add clipboard contents in existing Object Text using dxl script.

I searched around, including dxl_reference_manual but nothing helped.

The object in selection has some text for example "Already existing text in this object" and clipboard contents for example "My Clipboard text" should add at the beginning and form as a single object.

(Output should be something like below in a single object.)

My Clipboard text
Already existing text in this object

My code:

```
Skip    fGetSelectedObjects(Module in_mod) 
{     
    Skip    skpObjects = create()  // Return KEY and DATA both 'Object'
    if (null in_mod) return(skpObjects)
    Object  oCurr = current,
                    o
    for o in entire (in_mod) do
    {  if (isSelected(o)   or
           o == oCurr)              put(skpObjects, o, o)
    }
    return(skpObjects)
}     // end fGetSelectedObjects()
Skip    skpObjects = fGetSelectedObjects(current Module)
Object  o

for o in skpObjects do
{   // deal with the selected o
string s = o."Object text"
// I don't know the way to activate the object text attribute instead  of manual click. Thus it loops through selection and pastes the clipboard contents. 

  pasteToEditbox

//For Single Indentation use 360 points, double indentation 720 points and so on...

o."Object text" = richText (applyTextFormattingToParagraph(richText s,false,360,0))      

}
delete(skpObjects)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would be using a Skip for this. I would look to do the following:

```
// Create Variables
Module mod = current
Object obj = null
Buffer buf = create
string str = stringOf ( richClip )

// Loop through Module
for obj in entire ( mod ) do {
    // Grab the rich text from the clip and reset the buffer
    buf = str
    // Check if it's selected and object heading is empty
    if ( ( isSelected ( obj ) ) && ( obj."Object Heading" "" == "" ) ) {
        // If it is, add the text to the buffer
        buf += " " richText ( obj."Object Text" )
        // Set the object text with the clip stuff in front
        obj."Object Text" = richText ( buf )
    }
}

delete buf
```

Of note, this only works on items that have been specifically selected.

Edit- added exclusion for objects with an Object Heading. Unfortunately, DOORS does not (as far as I know) allow for non-contiguous object selection (the equivalent of ctrl-left click in Windows) which can be very frustrating.

Comment: That worked like charm. Very concise & clear.Thanks Russell. I had looped to put indent and bullets for objects in selection. And wanted to put the clipboard contents before this.

Comment: Can't I have exception for heading object in selection; script should exclude heading objects in selection.

Comment: Updated code to exclude objects that have an object heading- be aware that if you have something with both object heading and object text in the same object, it will be skipped.

Comment: Yeah! It does a job.